# Contar registros de una relacion

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy creando un panel de usuario donde cada uno podra ver sus novedades.

Estoy imprimiendo los tipos de novedades de las siguiente forma en mi vista.

```
@forelse ($typeNews as $typeNew)
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>{{$typeNew->name}}</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>CANTIDAD DE TIPO DE NOVEDADES </p>
  </div>
@empty
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>No hay Registros</p>
  </div>
@endforelse
```

Ya logre filtra las novedades por empleado que lo hago de la siguiente forma

```
$records = TypeNew::with(['records' => function($query) use ($id) {
  $query->where('employee_id', $id);
}])->get();
```

Como podria mostrar la cantidad de registros por tipo de novedad en cada usuario. 
Por ejemplo:

- Vacaciones 7
- Faltas 4
- Sanciones 3

Modelo TypeNew

```
public function records()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Record');
}
```

Modelo Record

```
public function employee()
{
    return $this->BelongsTo('App\Employee');
}

public function typeNew()
{
    return $this->BelongsTo('App\TypeNew');
}
```

Comment: Vos decir de crear un scope donde pase el ID del empleado y el ID del typo de novedad para filtrar y esto lo cuente?

Comment: Perfecto, acabo de agregar los datos del modelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hice fue utilizar la funcion [**`Whitcount`**](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

Mi función

```
$records = TypeNew::withCount(['records as employee_records_count' => function ($query) use ($id) {
               $query->where('employee_id',$id);
           }])->get();
```

Comment: Recuerda marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score 0):

También lo puedes lograr con un *accessor* declarado desde el modelo llamado `TypeNew` donde haces el conteo de la relación `records` de esta forma:

Modelo TypeNew

```
public function getRecordsCountAttribute()
{
    return $this->records->count();
}
```

Y posteriormente dentro de tu ciclo `foreach` la puedes llamar por su nombre de esta forma:

```
{{ $typeNew->records_count }}
```

**Referencia**

- [Laravel accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: El metodo withCount automaticamente genera el campo records_count

Comment: Claro que si @FrancoSanchez esto no es mas que otra opción

Comment: Sisi, perfecto. Son cosas que con el tiempo voy anotando para tener en cuanto a futuro. Valoro tu tiempo en dejarme otras opciones